# How submit a project to Ubuntu Software Center with Quickly

Tags: software-center, application-development, quickly

Which are all the steps? I'm going to reply below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some doubts submiting an app to the Ubuntu Software Center for the Ubuntu App Showdown. Here there are all the commands for a right submit:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application yourProject
cd yourProject
quickly configure bzr lp:~launchpadUsername/yourProject/trunk
quickly configure ppa launchpadUsername/yourProject
python setup.py build_i18n
save "Releasing version 0.1"
bzr push --overwrite lp:yourPPAName 
quickly package --extras
sed -i -e 's/Build-Depends:\ /Build-Depends:\ libglib2.0-bin, \ /' debian/control
Open debian/changelog > Change your email to your public key
debuild -S
dput ppa:launchpadUsername/yourPPAName ../project_version_source.changes
```

Submit the app to http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/, remember attach [the file](http://developer.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Ubuntu-App-Showdown-Participation-Details.txt) in the comments and the PPA!!! You don't need upload a package or file, just with the PPA will be fine :)

Comment: Note that we fixed the bug in the `submitubuntu` command, so if you install the Quickly version from `precise-proposed`, as described in the [Ubuntu App Developer Blog](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/07/ubuntu-app-showdown-deadline-approaching-get-your-submissions-ready/), you can just a) replace the `save` command above with `quickly submitubuntu` and b) remove everything below the `bzr push` line. Much easier :)